# Browse all folders and subfolders to delete all files which contain a certain string

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, os.walk

I have several folders containing several subfolders each, containing 5-6 .txt files each which have lists of fruits (apples, pears, grapes, ect.) A handful of random .txt files, however, contain "chicken", and must be deleted.

I am trying to write a program which will browse each folder and subfolder, deleting the files which contain the string "chicken", but it does not seem to be working for some reason.

The following is the code I have thus far:

```
import os
DIR = r'C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\fruits'
for parent, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(DIR):
    for fn in filenames:
        found = False
        with open(os.path.join(DIR,filename)) as f:
            for line in f:
                if 'chicken' in line:
                    found = True
                    break
    if found:
        os.remove(os.path.join(DIR, fn))
```

I am getting errors such as

```
  File <stdin>, line 4, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

and I'm not sure why.

Any suggestions on how to make the code run smoothly are much appreciated!

Comment: you need indentation before the 'found = True' to match the above 'if' statement

Comment: I think your `open()` call should use `fn`, not `filename`.

Comment: Also, it looks like the `if found:` block should be indented one level deeper, as you want this to run after processing _each_ file, not after processing _all_ files.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why do you break and then delete when you can directly remove the file. You are on the right track in your code but the structure and indentation were wrong. I hope this helps solve your issue.

```
import os 

root = r'C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\fruits'
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):

    for name in files:
        # get file path 
        file_path = os.path.join(path, name)
        # read content of file 
        with open(file_path) as f:
            content = f.readlines()

        # delete if it include key word
        for line in content: 
            if "chicken" in line:
                os.remove(file_path)
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

you are having indentation issue. Use the below code inside for loop

```
for line in f:
    if 'chicken' in line:
        found = True
        break
```

Comment: @SteveArguin You can check this answer for further help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578022/python-2-5-2-trying-to-open-files-recursively. And also accept the correct answer whenever you problem is solved.